# Updating a PDF Barcode Field in iOS and Android Device

Tags: javascript, android, ios, pdf, acrobat

I have created one acrobat form using of the Radiobutton, Text Field, Button,CheckBox and Barcode in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

After that I had opened that form in the Adobe Reader and the updation of Barcode and all added javascript is working well in our deskstop on updating of data in our PDF created through **"Adobe Acrobat Pro"**.

But on trying same thing in our **"Android Mobile"** and **"iOS"** it is not working.

Any suggestion Regarding this?

Comment: The PDF viewers available for Android and iOS are too limited to properly handle barcode fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot generate barcode with today's software.**

The only way that Barcodes might work on Android is if you used a **Text Field** with a **Barcode font** (usually only applicable to 3-of-9 symbology), instead of a Barcode field.